# returning rvalue? Or : Why does copy constructor get called on `return <expression>`?

Tags: c++, return, copy-constructor, rvalue

I am suspecting I vaguely know the reason for what I am observing, but I would like confirmation or correction and some explanation to it.

I have the following code:

```
template <class T>
class C
{

public:

    C () = default;

    C(const C& rhs) : mem(rhs.mem)
    {
        std::cerr << "copy" << "\n";
    }

    // does not call copy constructor twice
    // friend C operator<<(C& src, unsigned shift)
    // {
    //     std::cerr << 1 << "\n";
    //     C tmp(src);
    //     std::cerr << 2 << "\n";
    //     tmp <<= shift;
    //     std::cerr << 5 << "\n";
    //     return tmp;
    // }

    // does call copy constructor twice
    friend C operator<<(C& src, unsigned shift)
    {
        std::cerr << 1 << "\n";
        C tmp(src);
        std::cerr << 2 << "\n";
        return (tmp <<= shift);
    }

    friend C& operator<<=(C& src, unsigned shift)
    {
        std::cerr << 3 << "\n";
        src.mem <<= shift;
        std::cerr << 4 << "\n";
        return src;
    }

    T mem;
};

int main()
{
    C<int> c1;

    c1 << 3;
}
```

I have two versions of `C<T>::operator<<(C<T>, unsigned)`

the difference is the one returns the result of an expression:

`return (tmp <<= shift);`

the other returns a variable:

`return tmp`

So far I thought the two functions would be semantically identical and the one with `return (tmp <<= shift);` simply be better style, like `return a + 1` would be better style than `int ret = a + 1; return ret`. This is apparently not so and probably only holds true for atomic data types. The output of the version with `return (tmp <<= shift);` looks like this:

```
1
copy
2
3
4
copy
```

The output of the other like this:

```
1
copy
2
3
4
5
```

Is my assumption right that infact `return (tmp <<= shift);` does not return `tmp` after invoking `<<=` on itm but rather create a new object as a copy of `tmp` after `<<=` has been invoked?

Comment: You should really test with different optimization levels if you're going to test when or if the copy constructor is called.  The output can be completely different depending on the compiler, compiler optimizations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When returning by value, the *return value* must be initialized.  The return value is an object of type `C` here.

In the case `return (tmp <<= shift);`, it means that `(tmp << shift)` is the initializer for a `C`.  Since that is an lvalue of type `C`, this is a copy-construction.

There is a special rule that for a return statement of the form `return identifier;` , then it can be move-construction even though `identifier` is an lvalue. But that rule doesn't extend to other expressions (yet).

The other version of your code does activate the special rule:

```
tmp <<= shift;
return tmp;
```

Here `tmp` may be treated as an rvalue, making it movable (and also this makes it a copy elision context).

In your testing your compiler implemented copy-elision. To test without copy-elision (if your compiler supports letting the user configure that) you'd need to also give your `C` a move-constructor. A user-provided copy-constructor suppresses implicit generation of a move-constructor.

Answer (score 0):

the `operator <<=` may not return the reference to the input parameter (maybe it will return reference to another `static`/`global` variable), so the compiler can not easily decide to use **return value optimization**, and need to invoke the copy constructor.

In your question: When you write `return (tmp <<= shift)` the compiler doesn't know whether or not `(tmp <<= shift)` will return reference to tmp, but if you write `return tmp` the compiler knows it and can optimize it out.